# Unable to access get method from request package in the function node

Tags: node.js, npm, node-red

I have added request module and made changes in main settings.js as per the documentation :

```
 // Anything in this hash is globally available to all functions.
    // It is accessed as context.global.
    // eg:
    //    functionGlobalContext: { os:require('os') }
    // can be accessed in a function block as:
    //    context.global.os

    functionGlobalContext: {
    requestModule:require('request').defaults({jar: true})
        // os:require('os'),
        // octalbonescript:require('octalbonescript'),
        // jfive:require("johnny-five"),
        // j5board:require("johnny-five").Board({repl:false})
    },
```

This is the code in one of my function nodes :

```
var request = context.global.requestModule;
request.get('http://192.168.0.44:3000' + '/api/stats',
function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
       console.log("could not process data");
    }
    else {
        var body = JSON.parse(data.body);
        msg.payload = body.deviceCount;
    }
});
return msg;
```

My node red version is (0.16.2)

Comment: Why do you need to use the request module for this? The http-request node will work just fine

Comment: I need to have some extra authentication process with each data access request which is not there in the default http-request node

Answer (score 0):

That won't work because you return `msg` before the async call back in the request object is called. The following should work:

```
var request = context.global.requestModule;
request.get('http://192.168.0.44:3000' + '/api/stats',
function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
       console.log("could not process data");
    }
    else {
        var body = JSON.parse(data.body);
        msg.payload = body.deviceCount;
        node.send(msg)
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction; but request.get is still not recognized from context.global.requestModule am I missing something regarding that?